# Запрос на другой сайт ajax в laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Есть два сайта на laravel, как сделать ajax запрос с одного сайта на другой?

На 1 сайте, с которого пытаюсь получить данные:

Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function ($router) {
    Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@test');
});
```

middleware - cors

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

HomeControlle@test

```
public function test() {
  return 'test';
}
```

На втором сайте, на котором пытаюсь получить данные

ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://site.ru/test',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  type: "GET",
  data: { },
  success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

В консоле получаю `error`

Comment: боюсь спросить, вы сюда `url: 'https://site.ru/test'` урл своего сайта подставляете?)

Comment: @P.Fateev Да, подставил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну первое это то, что кроссдоменный запрос делать НЕнужно. То есть запросы ко второму сайту должны быть из бэка первого. `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'` означает что любой домен сможет слать вам аякс запросы - это не безопасно. Хотя бы ип свой впишите.

---

Второе - если вы все таки пользуетесь CORS'ом, то нужно подставить в `crossDomain: true` в $ajax.

Третье - обработать `OPTIONS` (думаю тут можно найти [ответ](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/447) как это сделать). Потому, что первый аякс-запрос пойдет как OPTIONS, который проверить наличие позволенных методов, а второй уже уже будет тот которым вы хотите что то получить GET POST ...